# Power Apps Data Table Empty

Tags: canvas, filter, datatables, powerapps, is-empty

I have data table control and it will retrieve the data from my collection. Till now it's fine. Now I want to make the data table empty without using any other controls like a button, or trash icon. Is there any possibility of using the direct function to make the data table empty?[image]

Comment: What do you mean making it empty without any interaction? When should it be empty? Update your question with a little more detail on your overall scenario.

Comment: Like, without using clear or clear collect function. Instead of this any direct formula is there to make the data table empty

Comment: Do you mean something like if variable is true use collection otherwise use empty table?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I don't get an Idea, Could you send any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example with using a variable.
Have a button with:

```
OnSelect = UpdateContext({ showTable: !showTable })
```

Then update the data table with:

```
Items = If (showTable, colEmployeeRegistration )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following way:

1. Add the following code on your screen `OnVisible` property:

```
Set(ShowData, true);
```

2. Add a button and add the following code in its `OnSelect` property:

```
Set(ShowData, !ShowData);
```

3. Replace your **Items** code with the following code:

```
Filter(colEmployeeRegistration, Or(ShowData, Name = "    "))
```

By this first, your whole data will be visible as your flag (`ShowData`) is set to `true`. Once you click the button flag will be set to `false` and the second condition will be checked i.e. `Name = "    "`, which I assume will never happen. Hence, the table will be blank.

You can also replace this condition `Name = "    "`, with any other condition, which always results in a `false` value.